# Wrapper implementation method to get user notifications in Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, java

I'm trying to build an app that requires me to get the user notifications for a particular Stack Exchange user.

Now, I'm trying to use Java to accomplish this and I came across this wrapper library: [StackWrap4J](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stackwrap4j/?source=dlp). However, I can't find a method to help me.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below java wrapper, notification support is there.

https://github.com/sanjivsingh/stackoverflow-java-sdk

For more detail, follow docs https://github.com/sanjivsingh/stackoverflow-java-sdk/wiki

**Query Example** :

```
StackExchangeApiQueryFactory queryFactory = StackExchangeApiQueryFactory.newInstance(
    applicationKey, accessToken,StackExchangeSite.STACK_OVERFLOW);

// get all notifications
PagedList<Notification> notifications = queryFactory
            .newNotificationApiQuery().list();

//  get unread notifications
PagedList<Notification> notification1s = queryFactory
    .newNotificationApiQuery().listNotificationsUnread();


// get notifications by userId
PagedList<Notification> notification2s = queryFactory
.newNotificationApiQuery().withUserIds(2384778)
            .listUserNotifications();
```